# ctypes using HRESULT(python)

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

I'm writing a DLL which is being called using a python script as below:

```
 //sample.h
 #include<stdio.h>
 typedef struct _data
{
 char * name;
}data,*xdata;
__declspec(dllexport) void getinfo(data xdata,HRESULT *error);


//sample.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include"sample.h"
void get(data xdata,HRESULT *error)
{ 
  //something is being done here
}
```

Now, the python script that is used to call the above function is shown as below:

```
//sample.py
import ctypes 
import sys
from ctypes import *
mydll=CDLL('sample.dll')
class data(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('name',c_char_p)]

def get():
    xdata=data()
    error=HRESULT()
    mydll=CDLL('sample.dll')
    mydll.get.argtypes=[POINTER(data),POINTER(HRESULT)]
    mydll.get.restype = None
    mydll.get(xdata,error)
    return xdata.value,error.value

xdata=get()
error=get()
print "information=",xdata.value
print "error=", error.value
```

But the error that I'm getting after running the python script is :

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program:C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
File:minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\stdio\fgets.cpp
Expression:stream.valid()
```

Can anybody help me in solving the problem? And the python script that I had written, is it the correct way to write it?

Comment: The error indicates using `pythonw.exe` which doesn't create a console.  `fgets()` isn't shown in your code, but if it is trying to read from `stdin` that would be an invalid stream without a console.

Comment: The other thing I noticed is `data xdata` is a parameter to `getinfo`.  That type is not `POINTER(data)` in Python but just `data`.

Comment: You've also returned two values from your Python `get()`, so `xdata,error = get()` instead of `xdata=get()` and `error=get()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comments, I suspect the error with `fgets()` is in code not shown, but there are problems in the Python and C code shown as well.  Here's the DLL source I used, making sure to pass a pointer to the data structure:

```
typedef long HRESULT;

typedef struct _data {
    char * name;
} data;

// Make sure to pass a pointer to data.
__declspec(dllexport) void getinfo(data* pdata, HRESULT *error)
{
    pdata->name = "Mark";
    *error = 0;
}
```

And here's the corrected Python code:

```
from ctypes import *

class data(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('name',c_char_p)]

def get():
    xdata=data()
    error=HRESULT()
    mydll=CDLL('sample.dll')
    mydll.getinfo.argtypes=[POINTER(data),POINTER(HRESULT)]
    mydll.getinfo.restype = None
    mydll.getinfo(xdata,error)
    return xdata,error

# Correction in next two lines
xdata,error = get()
print "information =",xdata.name
print "error =", error.value
```

Output:

```
information = Mark
error = 0
```